# Dificuldade em interpretar diagrama de banco de dados

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, tabela-html

Boa Noite. Estou tendo alguns problemas em interpretar um diagrama que a partir dele vou fazer um banco sql. Minhas habilidades de programação não são muito boas e apreciaria muito uma ajuda. No caso vou usar o phpmyadmin para montar, só que tenho algumas dúvidas se não devo colocar as keys que tão na tabela motorista junto com dados de nome, cpf, etc.. como as chamarei elas? E como vou ligar essas tabelas? Desde já obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para confirmar: A pergunta é sobre SQL ou MySQL?

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida, pode explicar melhor?